Question about AC unit
The thermostat for my central air system is downstairs in the living room. The intake for the AC is in the hallway upstairs in between the two bedrooms. I have a breathing machine in my bedroom which generates a lot of hot air. Will the air conditioning load change substantially if I keep the bedroom door closed and use a fan in my bedroomw to expell the hot air to the outside?

The AC doesn't work harder, it may work longer.

possibly yes ...

your question wording is convoluted ... it contradicts itself in a span of a few words

The answer depends on where the replacement air is coming into the room from. If you have two windows in the room, with both open, and keep the vent closed where AC would enter your room, your fan is mostly pulling outside air in one window and exhausting it out the other. Then your room is mostly separate from the AC and the rest of the house.
If you only have one window, but still keep the AC vent closed, it also would be mostly separate, but that will limit how well you're exhausting hot air.  Some of the air going out will be pulled back in.
If you have your AC vent open, then you are drawing air conditioned air into your room to replace the air being vented out the window.  That likewise means that that air is being replaced by outside air coming in all over the rest of the house.  The air that comes in will be at the outside temperature, so one way or another your AC is cooling outside air.  If you live where it is humid in the summer, you are also bringing that humidity into your house, and your AC has to work harder because it will be condensing that humidity into liquid water.  In that case, your AC will be working harder, to not only cool, but also dehumidify your house.
